# CMake enable_language(CUDA) on Linux doesn't auto-include CUDA headers: how to resolve?

Tags: c++, cmake, cuda

I am trying to switch a C++/CUDA project to use the new enable_language(CUDA) CMake syntax. Everything works fine on Windows with MSVC, but on Linux / GCC the CUDA headers aren't found when I try to compile the project. I've simplified down to the following bare-bones example.

main.cpp:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include "cuda.h" //on Linux, yields "fatal error: cuda.h: No such file or directory" compile-time error

int main(int, char* []) {    
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8)
project(Test)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

enable_language(CUDA)

set(EXEC_FILES main.cpp)

add_executable(test_exec ${EXEC_FILES})
```

I've searched, but [examples](https://github.com/lukeyeager/cmake-cuda-example/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt) I could find so far with "enable_language(CUDA)" don't seem to do anything special to the targets or issue include_directories / target_include_directories commands.

Aside:

- on Windows, I'm using CUDA 9.2, MSVC 2017, and CMake 3.12.1;
- on Linux, I'm using CUDA 9.2, GCC 5.4.0, and CMake 3.12.0.

How can I modify CMake correctly to make sure the CUDA header directory is used on all platforms?